# C# WebAPI parse Json data with extra braces

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api

This may be a very rare scenario, but I ended up with a problem and not finding any solution.

I have a WebAPI controller written with MVC WebAPI in C#. I have a post method which receives the custom object.

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage SendEmail([FromBody]Email email)
{

}
```

Below is the Email class, note that EmailData is of `dynamic` type.

```
public class Email
{
    public string EmailTo { get; set; }

    public dynamic EmailData { get; set; }
}
```

When I am sending `JSON` payloads as the post, EmailData property is adding extra curly braces '{}' into the object. This is giving me a problem because my dynamic data is not able to parse `JSON` with extra curly braces '{}'.

```
{
  "EmailFrom": "abc.xyz@abc.com",
  "EmailData": {
    "FirstName": "Rushi",
    "LastName": "Joshi"}
}
```

If this is happening because of the `dynamic` type, then I don't want to change type as I am not sure what all Key/Value requester may send. I am using `dynamic` data to extract data from it.

This shows EmailData being parsed and adding extra curly braces.

[image]

Comment: I do not see any "extra braces"... Email data is an object and is being serialized to json as an object. That is how objects are defined in json, inside a set of curly braces.

Comment: Those aren't extra, it shows nested, which it is.

Comment: You have a Web API controller.  "written with MVC WebAPI"  No, it's written with Web API.  This question doesn't involve MVC.

Comment: Why does EmailData have to be dynamic?  You can have a class with nullable fields and they'll just not be set if not specified in the Json...

Answer (score 3):

Use `Dictionary` object instead of dynamic, it will bind your key value pair data,

```
    public class Email
    {
        public string EmailTo { get; set; }

        public Dictionary<string,string> EmailData { get; set; }
    }
```

Your json will be,

```
{
  "EmailTo": "abc.xyz@abc.com",
  "EmailData": {
    "FirstName": "Rushi",
    "LastName": "Joshi"}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON provided is valid:
https://jsonlint.com/

An object with more than one property will always return in that format.

```
"EmailData": {
    "FirstName": "Rushi",
    "LastName": "Joshi"}
```

This is an EmailData object with two name/value pairs.You have an object nested inside your original object.

Here is some documentation to read up on for further clarification.
https://www.json.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the dynamic JSON in your Email class then you can use the Newtonsoft.Json package.

```
    public class Email
    {
        public string EmailTo { get; set; }

        public JOject EmailData { get; set; }
    }
```

It will store any type of the JSON. So you can parse the inner JSON object at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, yes you all gave a wonderful answer and special thanks to Stevenfowler16, who describe that this is correct way JSON object should be processed.

Thing is I can't remove the dynamic object type as that is coming from some other library, also I can't change anything into the signature of API. but yes below thing helped me.

```
em.EmailData = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(em.EmailData.ToString());
```

This serves my purpose but again thanks, everyone, your solution provide me some direction into it.

Regards

Rushi